# Continue with code after URLSession.shared.uploadTask is completed

Tags: swift, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am trying to communicate with Swift to a php-website using the command "uploadTask". The site is sending Data back, which is working well. The result from the website is stored in the variable "answer". But how can I actually use "answer" AFTER the uploadTask.resume() was done?

When running the file, it always prints:
"One" then "three" then "two".

I know that I could do things with "answer" right where the section "print("two")" is. And at many examples right there the command    "DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }" is used. But I explicitly want to finish the uploadTask and then continue with some more calculations.

```
   func contactPHP() {

    print("One")

    let url = "http://....php" // website to contact
    let dataString = "password=12345" // starting POST
    let urlNS = NSURL(string: url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlNS! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) // convert to utf8 string

    URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
    {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            let answer = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            print("Two")
        }
        }.resume()  // Starting the dataTask

  print("Three")

 // Do anything here with "answer"

}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

I already tried it with a completion handler. But this does not work either. This also gives me "One", "Four", "Two", "Three"

```
func test(request: URLRequest, dataD: Data?, completion: @escaping (NSString) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
    {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        } else {
            let answer = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            print("Two")
            completion(answer)
        }
        }.resume()  // Starting the dataTask
    }

let blubb = test(request: request, dataD: dataD) { (data) in
    print("Three")
}

print("Four")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `URLSession` function that has the completion handler:

```
URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: URLRequest, from: Data?, completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
```

Replace your `uploadTask` function with something like this:

```
URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD) { (data, response, error) in

     if let error = error {
          // Error
     }

     // Do something after the upload task is complete

}
```

> **Apple Documentation**
>
> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume()
>   method. If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of
>   the completion handler block contains the resource data, and the error
>   parameter is nil.
>
> If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and
>   the error parameter contain information about the failure. If a
>   response from the server is received, regardless of whether the
>   request completes successfully or fails, the response parameter
>   contains that information.

When the upload task is complete, the completion handler of the function is called. You could also implement the delegate's `optional func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)` function.